# How to create installer package in linux by using YUM or Apt package manager?

Tags: linux, yum, apt

Need to create an Installer package in linux by using either YUM or apt Package manager

Comment: Hi Gio gram, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you [edit] your question to add a bit more detail; for example, can you describe what attempts you've made so far and what _specific_ problems you have run into?

Answer (score 1):

On debian based platforms you can use https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall . First do all the steps required for the compilation, and compile it with **make**. Then

```
checkinstall --install=no
```

to create a .deb for the binary you compiled. If checkinstall is not installed on your system, you can install it with

```
apt install checkinstall
```